# Eigenvalues of sum of two matrices

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have a family of matrices depending on a parameter $\mu$ of the form:
$$A(\mu)=A_0+D(\mu),$$
where $D(\mu)$ is a diagonal matrix and $A_0$ does not depend on $\mu.$ The diagonal of $D(\mu)$ is a vector which looks like:
$$\left(0, \ldots ,0, \mu, \ldots, \mu,2\mu,\ldots, 2\mu,\ldots \ldots,8\mu,\ldots,8\mu   \right).$$
 I need to diagonalize $A(\mu)$ for a large range of values of $\mu,$ and since the dimensions of the matrices I am working with is huge, this is expensive. I was thus wondering whether there's a way to simplify the problem knowing that the $\mu-$dependence is only in the diagonal part of the matrix. Since the diagonalization of $D(\mu)$ is trivial for each $\mu,$ is there some way in which just diagonalizing $A_0$ would allow me to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A(\mu)$ much more quickly?

Comment: Without any information on $D(\mu)$, it's impossible to answer. For instance, for the said range for $\mu$, is $D(\mu)$ much larger than $A_0$? This would allow us to find good approximations.

Comment: No, they are comparable. I'll add some more details